# Design - How to structure filters taking advantage of OOP in Rails API app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop

My app shows items in a feed. This items are ratings made by different users. Ratings can have a value, a review, etc.
Usual case is logged in user asking for feed (/users/feed). The controller takes the action:

```
def feed
    if authenticate_with_token
      imos_and_cursor = Feed.new(RandomItemFeeder.new(params[:cursor], @current_user)).feed
      render json: {cursor: imos_and_cursor[imos_and_cursor.length-1], imos: imos_and_cursor[0..imos_and_cursor.length-2]} 
    end
  end
```

`Feed` is the boss here. It controles what is served (it serves to respond with items but it also will know how to respond for feeding the people call (index of users basically).
Here are some of the feeders I have:
FriendsFeeder
RandomItemsFeeder
MostRecentItemsFeeder

Following is RandomItemFeeder, responsible of feed with random items:

```
class RandomItemFeeder < Feeder

    def feed

        influencers_ids = User.influencers.distinct(:id)
        friends = User.friends(@watching_user).distinct(:id) if @watching_user
        source_users = influencers_ids.concat(friends)

        Rating.random_from_influencers(@watching_user, source_users).scroll(@current_cursor) do |rating, cursor|
            @next_cursor = cursor
            @feed << ImoPresenter.new(Imo.new(rating), @watching_user)
        end

        @feed << @next_cursor.to_s

    end

end
```

**Presenters**

I've structured the rendering of jsons with presenters, so I have different presenters for different cases (feed, user profile, etc.).

Now, I want to incorporate filters. For example, I want that RandomItemFeeder feeds with just items of last 5 five years (obviously, Item model has corresponding fields).

The question is how can I incorporate this filtering utilizing best OOP practices. At the end, is just a scope and i can implement it in different ways, but I just want to do it right now so that I don't have to come back and refactor everything.

Thanks in advance.